# Gráficos com Crystal Reports

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

Bom dia!

Tenho um relatório que mostra o desempenho de vendas por vendedor com comparação por períodos. Gostaria de plotar esses dados com um gráfico de linhas da seguinte forma:

```
Eixo vertical (Y): Soma de valor de venda (por mês)
Eixo horizontal (X): Meses do ano
Linhas: uma linha para cada ano
```

Assim posso fazer a comparação dos valores de venda com os mesmos períodos em anos passados, mas não estou sabendo como plotar uma linha para cada ano.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um campo de ano na sua base de dados ou crie formula  para o Ano, use a function
Year()

Insira um gráfico, tipo Linha (Linhas empilhadas)

```
Na alteração de :
   Ano(formula ou campo)
   Data (formate exibição para mes)

Mostrar valores
   Valor
```

Comment: CR é programação.

Comment: Eu sei, mas tem assuntos que não é e seria legal termos um local para podermos perguntas sobre estes assuntos. Se tiver dúvidas leia mais em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2482/101 o que estamos fazendo.